# Different behaviour on combining diacritics between String.Split() and String.IndexOf()

Tags: c#, .net, unicode

If I have a string that contains combining diacritics, there seems to be some confusion between behaviour between different string functions. If I use `String.IndexOf()`, it will combine the diacritic and find the correct character. If I use `String.Split()`, for some reason it will not combine them and will not find the combined character.

Example code:

```
string test = "abce\u0308fgh";
Console.WriteLine(test.IndexOf("e"));
Console.WriteLine(test.IndexOf("ë"));
```

This will work as expected, meaning the e is not found, but the ë is. But for some reason this doesn't behave similarly:

```
string test = "abcde\u0308fgh";
Console.WriteLine(test.Split('e').Length.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(test.Split('ë').Length.ToString());
```

For some reason `Split()` will not combine the diacritic and will split by e, but not by ë.

Is there some reason for this functionality and is there a way to either have an `IndexOf()` function that doesn't combine the diacritic, or preferably a `Split()` function that does?

**Edit: Noticed I had earlier written wrong code, it had 'e' and not "e"**

```
string test = "abce\u0308fgh";
Console.WriteLine(test.IndexOf('e'));
Console.WriteLine(test.IndexOf('ë'));
```

This behaves as the `Split()` also, so it is not between the methods, it's between taking a character or a string.

Comment: Add `test = test.Normalize();`

Comment: @HansPassant Not always can the data be normalized, the diacritics (or other information) may be desireable to be kept separated. Otherwise `Normalize()` would be the way to go. Also I'm not sure if there is a combined character for each diacritic.

Comment: You'll need to come up with a better example.  I seriously doubt you'll find one.

Comment: @HansPassant The question is about methods working differently. It is not "how do I handle the data losing diacritics." Theory versus practice. And I actually did have a not-so-nice dataset of words with different diacritics that I had to handle, keeping the diacritics separate for linguistic purposes. It was a requirement in the project and I noticed these differences. I didn't start to question why they want it that way, they have their reasons. SO always likes MVCs, not "provide a full example of a real life situation where you need this."

Comment: Using String.Normalize() is a very simple workaround with an as-yet unknown failure mode.  If you don't want to use it then just don't use Split().  You can write your own with String.IndexOf().  It will not be as fast, performance and accuracy are always opposing goals.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you for your input. As I already said, it has the failure that after it part of the diacritics are gone, since they have been combined. It cannot be used when the diacritics need to be preserved as separate code points. That failure mode is not unknown. It will work in many cases, but not in every one of them.

Comment: String.Normalize() takes an argument, you can denormalize it again.  Why you'd want to do so is the ten-thousand dollar question that nobody can see the point of in the Q.

Comment: @HansPassant And if I did, e.g. ä\u0301 would denormalize into three codepoints, which is not wanted, since it was two codepoints originally. There is no Normalize-Denormalize sequence available that would handle e\u0308ä\0301 without changing it in any way. As I said, this is linguistic material and they use it how they want to. There are several diacritics used to modify the letters and they like sometimes getting the base characters easily, sometimes matching the combined one. This still has no relevance to the original question "why do these behave differently."

Comment: Hmya, Unicode has well-documented rules about this and .NET was written with the assumption that a program follows those rules.  You can break them, you'll get to hold the pieces.

Comment: You probably should be using [StringInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.stringinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class which has similar methods that take into account all elements composing single "character".

Answer (score 1):

Actually, when I copy and paste your example code into a blank program, I get exactly the behavior I might expect: both `IndexOf()` and `Split()` do not treat the combined character as the passed in `ë` search character. I.e. the call to `IndexOf('ë')` returns -1 for me, consistent with how you describe the behavior of `Split()`.

That said, if you want `Split()` to treat such two-character representations of single-character versions as if they were in fact originally the single-character version, you can just call `string.Normalize()` before `Split()`. For example:

```
Console.WriteLine(test.Normalize().Split('ë').Length);
```

The `Normalize()` method has an overload to let you control the exact type of normalization, should that be required (it's not in the example you've provided).

Comment: Actually, my code was wrong, it seems! I'll amend. I had "e" in my original code and for the example here I wrote 'e' and they behave differently.